# Rails RSS Feed not rendered as XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss

I have some Atom Feeds that works fine. I need now an RSS Feed for Flipboard, but when I try to generate it isn't rendered as xml and looks invalid.

Routes.rb

```
  get '/flipboard_feed', :controller => 'news_feed', :action => 'flipboard_feed', :format => 'rss'
```

Controller

```
def flipboard_feed
    # this will be the name of the feed displayed on the feed reader
    @title = "Feed title"
    # the news items
    @items = Content.published.limit(50)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.rss { render :layout => false }
    end
  end
```

Then I have a `flipboard_feed.rss.builder`

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version => "1.0"
xml.rss :version => '2.0' do
  xml.channel do
    xml.title @title
    xml.link "#{root_url}flipboard_feed"
    xml.description 'xxxx'
    xml.language "it"

    @items.each do |article|
      xml.item do
        xml.title article.name
        xml.link show_resource_url(article)
        xml.guid article.id
        xml.pubDate article.published_at.to_s(:rfc822)
        xml.dc(:creator, article.author_name)
        xml.description article.summary
        xml.enclosure $imgix.path(article.main_image.path).to_url(w: 1000, h: 500, fit: 'crop', auto:'format,compress')
        xml.category article.sections.map(&:name).join(', ')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The feed is rendered but it's not an xml and is not validated. Why?

Comment: Can you show what is being rendered?

Comment: @Joel_Blum https://www.dday.it/flipboard_feed.rss

Comment: Seems fine except for the guid, which needs to be a URL and the missing dc namespace: https://www.rssboard.org/rss-validator/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dday.it%2Fflipboard_feed.rss